# When should I use mb_strpos(); over strpos();?

Tags: php, string, strpos

Huh, looking at all those string functions, sometimes I get confused. One is using all the time `mb_` functions, the other - plain ones, so the question is simple...

When should I use `mb_strpos();` and when should I go with the plain one (`strpos();`)?

And, yes, I'm aware about that `mb_` functions stand for multi-byte, but does it really mean, that if I'm working with only utf-8 encoded strings, I should stick with `mb_` functions?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should use the `mb_` functions whenever you expect to work with text that's not pure ASCII. I.e. you can work with the regular string functions, even if you're using UTF-8, as long as all the strings you're using them on only contain ASCII characters.

```
strpos('foobar', 'foo')  // fine in any (ASCII-compatible) encoding, including UTF-8
strpos('ふーばー', 'ふー') // won't work as expected, use mb_strpos instead
```

Comment: And what about performance when using `mb_` functions on UTF-8 strings containing only ASCII characters? Would it be slower/faster/no significant difference (as always..)? *interested because `mb_` looks like de facto choice when working with UTF-8 strings, even if they contain only ASCII*

Comment: @Tom As always: profile it, if you're concerned. :) My hunch is that it would be slightly slower, but not in any significant way, unless you're working on massively large strings.

Comment: no point in profiling if the result is ms's in either way (and lets not argue on this one, of course in long-running scripts it could become noticeable) and/or you can _kind of_ predict the result logically. But, huh, I already thought that it'd be slower, just wanted to know different opinion. Anyways, thanks, accepted!

Answer (score 4):

Yes, if working with UTF-8 *(which is a multi-byte encoding : one character can use more than one byte)*, you should use the `mb_*` functions.

The non-mb functions will work on bytes, and not characters -- which is fine when 1 character == 1 byte ; but that's not the case with *(for example)* UTF-8.

Comment: Should be: "...that's not ***necessarily*** the case with UTF-8." The lower UTF-8 ranges are identical to ASCII and work just fine with the regular string functions.

Comment: Chose deceze's answer because of _ASCII only_ statement.

Comment: @deceze just curious, are there any pitfalls to using mb_* all the time rather than the regular string functions? Microptimization aside.

Answer (score 3):

I'd say yes, here's the description from the php documentation:

mbstring provides multibyte specific string functions that help you deal with multibyte encodings in PHP. In addition to that, mbstring handles character encoding conversion between the possible encoding pairs. **mbstring is designed to handle Unicode-based encodings such as UTF-8 and UCS-2 and many single-byte encodings for convenience**....

If you're not sure that the mb extension is loaded, you should check before because mb-string is a non-default extension.