# mb_strpos vs strpos, what's the difference?

Tags: php, utf-8, strpos

Yes: I know. We should use mb_* function when we're working with multibyte char. But when we're using strpos?
Let's take a look this code (saved in utf-8)

```
var_dump(strpos("My symbol utf-8 is the €.", "\xE2\x82\xAC")); // int(23)
```

There is a difference of using mb_strpos? Does't makes this work the same jobs? After all, does't *strpos* seek **a string** (multiple byte)?  Is there a reason to use instead strpos?

Comment: This might help :: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5712226/when-should-i-use-mb-strpos-over-strpos

Answer (score 17, accepted):

For UTF-8, matching the byte sequence is exactly the same as matching character sequence.

So they both will find the needle at exactly the same point, but `mb_strpos` counts full UTF-8 byte sequencees **before** the needle, where as `strpos` calculates any bytes. So if your string had another multi-byte UTF-8 sequence, the results would be different:

```
strpos("My symbolö utf-8 is the €.", "€") !== mb_strpos("My symbolö utf-8 is the €.", "€", 0, "UTF-8")
```

But:

```
strpos("My symbol utf-8 is the €.", "€") === mb_strpos("My symbol utf-8 is the €.", "€", 0, "UTF-8")
```

Answer (score 8):

Depending on the character set in use and the string being searched for, this may or may not make a difference.

`strpos()` looks for the byte sequence that is passed as the needle.

`mb_strpos()` does the same thing *but* it also respects character boundaries.

So `strpos()` will match if the byte sequence occurs anywhere in the string. `mb_strpos()` will only match if the byte sequence also represents a valid set of complete characters.

Comment: That's not true, `mb_strpos()` will also find invalid set of characters. The only difference is return values and arguments (characters instead of bytes), but invalid characters are handled just the same.

Answer (score 5):

I don't the find above example fully transparent and some users may be confused.

`mb_string()` should be used for multi-byte encoding, and what is multi-byte encoding you have explained in other questions, e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/748965/what-is-a-multibyte-character-set).

Recently we use mostly UTF encodings as `UTF-8` in this example (also `UTF-16`) which is multi-byte character set, however usually we use only ASCII character sets (e.g. for English) and the result of `strpos` and `mb_strpos` is identical for them.

The difference is visible when we use multi-byte characters, i.e. Chinese characters.

```
echo mb_internal_encoding(); //UTF-8

echo strpos('我在买绿茶', '在'); //3

echo mb_strpos('我在买绿茶', '在'); //1
```

So obviously it's applicable to Chinese characters, but also to **emoji** which some are not aware of.

To give wider view how it works I show length of the following string with `strlen()` and `mb_strlen()` functions.

```
echo strlen('我在买绿茶'); //15

echo mb_strlen('我在买绿茶'); //5
```